# Differential equation (exact solution)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Currently I'm working mostly in matlab using newton-rhapsons, fixpoint iteration etc, as approximations for a solution. But I'm currently stuck with a problem where I'm supposed to show that the function:

$dz/dt = (\lambda )z(t)$
$z(0)=1$

Im supposed to show that the exact solution to the problem is:

$z((n+1)\Delta)$ = $e^{-\lambda\Delta }z(n\Delta t)  $

I tried doing integrating factor and to separate it, but I'm not even close to the solution, how do I prove this? thanks in advance!

Comment: If $z(t)=z(0)e^{\lambda t}$ then $z(t+s)=e^{\lambda s}z(t)$, in particular $z((n+1)\Delta)=e^{\lambda\Delta}z(n\Delta)$, qed. (And please correct the sign in your $e^{-\lambda\Delta}$.)

Comment: "Im supposed to show that the exact solution to the problem is:" this is not a solution but a property of the solution.

Comment: "I tried doing integrating factor and to separate it": the equation is seprable as it stands and is one of the easiest to integrate. What are you missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a finite $\Delta t$. Then

$$z'(t)\approx\frac{\Delta z}{\Delta t}=\frac{z(t+\Delta t)-z(t)}{\Delta t}=-\lambda z(t)$$

from which you get, with $t=n\Delta t$,

$$z((n+1)\Delta t)\approx z(n\Delta t)-\lambda z(n\Delta t)\Delta t=z(n\Delta t)(1-\lambda\Delta t).$$

Then by recurrence

$$z(n\Delta t)\approx z(0)(1-\lambda\Delta t)^n,$$ or

$$z(t)\approx z(0)\left(1-\frac{\lambda t}n\right)^n$$ which you should ring a bell.

Indeed, when you take the limit $n\to\infty$, you obtain

$$z(t)=z(0)e^{-\lambda t}.$$

This is an *empirical* way to solve the differential equation.

With this expression, the exact recurrence is indeed

$$z((n+1)\Delta t)=z(n\Delta t)e^{-\lambda\Delta t}.$$

Answer (score 1):

The equation can be written as

$$\frac{dz}{z}=\lambda dt$$

which gives, after integration

$$\ln(\frac{z}{\mu})=\lambda t$$

and the exact solution is:

$$z(t)=\mu e^{\lambda t}$$

$$=e^{\lambda t}$$

since $z(0)=1$.

an approched solution is obtained by

$$\frac{z((n+1)\Delta t)-z(n\Delta t)}{\Delta t}=\lambda z(n\Delta t)$$

and

$$z((n+1)\Delta t)=z(n\Delta t)(1+\lambda \Delta t)$$

Comment: yes, thats pretty much how far I've come as well, but how do you approach from this to the exact solution I'm supposed to get?

Comment: The OP is interested in the exact solution, not "an approched solution".

Comment: @Did I gave both solutions: exact and approched.

Comment: can you show how you get the last approched solution, I dont know how you got it.

Comment: @Stratbomber And now .is it ok?

Comment: "I gave both solutions: exact and approched" No, you did not explain the exact formula giving $z((n+1)\Delta)$ in terms of $z(n\Delta)$. (And "approched" does not exist, you might mean "approximate" instead.)

Comment: @Did In the equations of  the question, it is $\lambda$ or $-\lambda$.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam Yes, at present, "the equations of the question" are contradictory.